# Regex match Unicode 'Punctuation' category c++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, unicode

According to various [documentation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html), to match **any** punctuation I need to use the "\p{P}" pattern

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

...

std::string str = "Hello'\"#%&!.:,?¿World";
std::regex re("\\p{P}", std::regex::extended );
str = std::regex_replace(str, re, " ");
```

But I get an error when I do the above, so my question is, how do I match all punctuations \p{P}?

Comment: In C++, only if you are using PCRE library. Which one are you using?

Comment: hum, I am using VS2015, not sure what library they are using.
Do I need to download another library or select something else?

Comment: Features like unicode character classes are not available in the standard regex module (whatever the mode used: basic, extended, ECMAscript...). You can use boost to have them.

Comment: What about the `[[:punct:]]` character class? Does it meet your need?

Comment: If I understand [[:punct:]] correctly only the 'common' punctuation [!"#$%&'()*+,
 \-./:;<=>?@ [\\\]^_`{|}~] will be removed.
That does not include the punctuation from all character sets. But I could be wrong of course.

Comment: @n.m, it was in the link I provided in my original post, but it is available in multiple places.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the link at first. Wrong documentation. The grammar of extended regular expressions is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04). Your link describes PCRE. Not supported in the C++ standard.

Comment: Your string literal is not strictly conforming C++. It contains characters outside of the basic source character set. C++ is still pretty much ASCII. Different compilers in different environments will do different things with your code. You better mention your compiler, standard library, OS, and every relevant detail about your environment.

Comment: @n.m. "strictly conforming" is not a term defined in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my environment this `wchar_t` version of your program works as intended:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main ()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));

    std::wstring str =L"Hello'\"#%&!.:,?¿World";
    std::basic_regex<wchar_t> re(L"[[:punct:]]", std::regex::extended );
    str = std::regex_replace(str, re, L" ");
    std::wcout << str << std::endl;
}
```

I use both g++ and clang++ (with libc++) on Linux. Nobody can guarantee anything about your environment, but I'd hazard a guess that the latest VS should work too. `char32_t` may or may not be a better choice than `wchar_t` on Windows/VS platforms. VS does not fully conform to the standard in that its wchar_t cannot represent all elements of the extended character set. It's basically an UTF-16 code point. So if you have punctuation outside of BMP, a wchar_t regex may fail. char32_t regexps do not work with either of Linucx compilers/libraries; YMMV.

If you want to operate directly on UTF-8-encoded byte strings, I guess you're out of luck with the standard C++ library. You need a third-party regex library such as [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/). Alternatively, convert your UTF-8-encoded strings on the fly:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

int main ()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));

    std::string str ="Hello'\"#%&!.:,?¿World";
    std::regex re("[[:punct:]]", std::regex::extended ); // ¡No trabajo!
    str = std::regex_replace(str, re, " ");
    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> wconv;

    std::wstring wstr =  wconv.from_bytes(str);
    std::basic_regex<wchar_t> wre(L"[[:punct:]]", std::regex::extended );
    wstr = std::regex_replace(wstr, wre, L" ");
    str = wconv.to_bytes(wstr);
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does work with VS2015, I guess I now need a fairly good way of converting my std:: string to std::wstring

Comment: @SimonGoodman added some info on wchar_t vs char32_t and conversion.